# How to organize objects by their attributes in an AJAX function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Please excuse me if this seems elementary I've been stuck on this for weeks.
If you are using an AJAX success function to display data dynamically on your html page, and the data you are getting back from the server is in stdclass objects like so

```
    array( 
       [7] => stdClass Object
        (
       [id] => 3
       [title] => Electrition
       [img] => 
       [description] => 
       [school] => 
       [location] => 1
       [url] => 
       [tablename] => 3
       [votes] => 0
       [name] => John Doe
       [NumJobsdone] => 4
           )

         [8] => stdClass Object
       (
        [id] => 2
        [title] => Electrition
        [img] => 
        [description] => 
        [school] => 
        [location] => 1
        [url] => 
        [tablename] => 2
        [votes] => 0
        [name] => Tico Marinez
        [NumJobsdone] => 6
        )

        [9] => stdClass Object
        (
        [id] => 2
        [title] => Engineer
        [img] => 
        [description] => 
        [school] => 
        [location] => 1
        [tablename] => 2
        [votes] => 0
        [name] => Jerry Smity
        [NumJobsdone] => 6
       )

     [10] => stdClass Object
       (
       [id] => 2
       [title] => Engineer
       [img] => 
       [description] => 
       [school] => 
       [location] => 1
       [url] => 
       [tablename] => 2
       [votes] => 0
        [name] => Laura Bastian
       [NumJobsdone] => 6
         )
        )
```

How do you write a jquery function that can iterate through the data and create paragraph tags to label the output and an unordered list within a div of the corresponding objects?

ex. you are trying to create two groupings, electritions and engineers, and list the names of the individuals.

It seems simple but when i used a $.each method in my success function, I created a paragraph tag for every object that had the attribute I was organizing the objects by, and when I tried to use the sort method, I could only compare two or three objects at a time and not iterate through a long list of several objects.

Say the desired output looked something like this

```
     <div id="accordion">
        <p> Electrition</p>
        <div>
        <ul>
          <li>jon</li>
          <li>jill</li>         
       </ul>
       </div>

        <p>Engineer</p>
       <div>
        <ul>
          <li>jerry</li>
          <li>laura</li>
       </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: You first need to think it. The solution is pretty easy, just save them in a array and then loop, check and print.

Comment: Show what you've tried in addition to describing what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

Try jquery each..

```
$.each(array, function (index,value) {
$('#accordion').append("<p>"+ value.title +"</p><div><ul><li>" + value.name + "</li></ul></div>")});
```

array is the name of the array being passed back
[I created a codepen solution for you](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOppYx) you can do more with the other elements as well

> [Jquery each question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157126/jquery-each-array-of-objects)
>
> [JQuery Each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)